# How can I test a plain text email that has an HTML body?

Tags: gmail, html-email

If an email contains HTML, Gmail, for example, renders the body as HTML. How can I check that the plain text version also works?

Comment: For a quick hacky test just set your test email account to not accept html emails only plain text. That way you can see how it looks.

Comment: I can't seen how to do that in Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an email on Gmail click on the small button on the right of *reply* and choose 'show original'.

[image: show original]

If it is a multi-part message it will show you what was sent to the Gmail server. Do a quick search for:

```
----=_---NextPart--=_
```

You should  be able to find the multi part messages which consists of text/plain or text/html, similar to below:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable


Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

If your platform allows to send the multi-part individually then you can send them separate and you will get both the emails separate in your inbox.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That does not necessarily show the plain text version in display form. It usually shows show encoded source form.

Comment: @ChrisJJ 
Of course it shows only the _encoded source form_. The question was **How can I check that the plain text version also works?**

Comment: I know what the question was, thanks. I asked it. Regardless, your suggestion is not a solution. It does not necessarily show the plain text version in display form. It usually shows show encoded source form. It doesn't decode. Thanks anyway for the thought.

Comment: @ChrisJJ  
Example with a long plain text https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk34V.png AND example without plain text https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Owu2.png. Some times it is encoded yes but it gives indication that plain text works.

Comment: Your plain text example isn't decoded. So the bext one can say it this method sometimes gives an indication that plain text might work. I am seeking better. Thanks anyway.

Comment: None of the two are mine. Both images are _examples_ of what companies are sending out.